# Why are arrow key presses not registering in Node-RED dashboard to send input to http request node?

Tags: node-red

new to node red and coding. I wrote a code in dashboard template node for displaying arrow key press button, at the same time where user also able to click the arrow button and send input to http request node to perform task. However, the arrow key press in dashboard didn't produce any input to the node red and i got no idea why. Anyone can help?

Below is the code i created in template node:

```
<div>
    <style>
        .arrow-keypad {
            display: grid;
            grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
            grid-gap: 5px;
            justify-items: center;
            align-items: center;
            width: 200px;
            margin: 0 auto;
        }

        .arrow-button {
            display: flex;
            align-items: center;
            justify-content: center;
            width: 50px;
            height: 50px;
            font-size: 24px;
            background-color: #333;
            color: #fff;
            border: none;
            border-radius: 50%;
            cursor: pointer;
            transition: background-color 0.3s;
        }

        .arrow-button:hover {
            background-color: #555;
        }

        .arrow-button.up {
            grid-column: 2 / 3;
            grid-row: 1 / 2;
        }

        .arrow-button.left {
            grid-column: 1 / 2;
            grid-row: 2 / 3;
        }

        .arrow-button.right {
            grid-column: 3 / 4;
            grid-row: 2 / 3;
        }

        .arrow-button.down {
            grid-column: 2 / 3;
            grid-row: 3 / 4;
        }
    </style>

    <div class="arrow-keypad">
        <button class="arrow-button up" onclick="sendCommand('left')">
            <i class="fa fa-arrow-up"></i>
        </button>

        <button class="arrow-button left" onclick="sendCommand('left')">
            <i class="fa fa-arrow-left"></i>
        </button>

        <button class="arrow-button right" onclick="sendCommand('right')">
            <i class="fa fa-arrow-right"></i>
        </button>

        <button class="arrow-button down" onclick="sendCommand('backward')">
            <i class="fa fa-arrow-down"></i>
        </button>
    </div>
</div>

<script>
    function sendCommand(command) {
        let vx = 0;
        let vth = 0;

        if (command === 'forward') {

            msg.payload = { "vx": 1, "vth": 0};
            return msg;

        } else if (command === 'backward') {
    
            msg.payload = { "vx": -1, "vth": 0};
            return msg;

        } else if (command === 'left') {
            
            msg.payload = { "vx": 0, "vth": 0.5};
            return msg;

        } else if (command === 'right') {
           
            msg.payload = { "vx": 0, "vth": -0.5};
            return msg;
        }
        
        
    }
</script>
```

i expectig that users can click the four arrow key in dashbaord ui and it will generate input to node red in order to automatically send input to http request node to perform task like moving forward, backward, turn left and right.